# Sub-range erasure in the map data structure

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance

Lets say I want to build a c++ based library and there is an operation that involves erasure of subrange in map. Is there a way I can possibly implement that in amortized O(logn) at most.

I have tried different implementaion with `map.erase(begin, end)` where i have created `assign()` function and when i overwrite existing elements this is where `erase()` comes in.

Comment: For `std::map` the requirement is that does `erase(first, last)` at complexity `log(c.size()) + std::distance(first, last)` - so that should be close to your requirement. You don't need to erase to reassign though. It's probably more effective to just reassign the values. If you need to reassign the keys too, you could possibly extract, reassign and then insert.

Comment: The reason for the `std::distance(first, last)` is to run destructors and free memory. Working to avoid this expense means either accepting a memory leak, or complicating allocation to try reusing memory in a way that probably costs more time than you save.

Comment: Even without destructors to worry about, the `map` keeps accurate score of the number of entries. Counting the number of entries between two iterators takes O(N) in a classic RB tree unless I'm mistaken. Same reason why `list::splice` is O(N) with iterator ranges

Comment: sullmeister, perhaps you could tell us a little more about the actual use-case? Please provide some details.

Comment: It's relatively easy to do this in a B+tree, if you don't mind being left with O(log n) disconnected subtrees that you have to figure out how to delete.  If you make it an order statistic tree by recording the size of each node's subtree, then you can update the total size of the map.